# Why is this nonlinear transformation of an RKHS also an RKHS?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, computer-science, machine-learning, kernels, learning-theory

I came across this [paper](http://ecmlpkdd2017.ijs.si/papers/paperID194.pdf) (beginning of page 6) where they stated that if $f,h\in \mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is an RKHS, then $l_{h,f}=\left|f(x)-h(x)\right|^q$ where $q\geq 1$ also belongs to an RKHS since $f-h\in \mathcal{H}$ and $l_{h,f}$ can be seen as a nonlinear mapping of $f-h$.

What I don't understand is the following:

- Why is this type of nonlinear mapping of an RKHS also an RKHS? I have not found a proof of this anywhere.
- They then say that $\left\|l_{h,f}\right\|^2_{\mathcal{H}_{k_1}}\leq \left\|h-f\right\|^{2q}_{\mathcal{H}_k}$, but I don't understand why this is true. I looked at the source they reference but there doesn't seem to be anything relevant there.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

If $f,h\in \mathcal{H}_K$, where $\mathcal{H}_K$ is an RKHS, and $l_{h,f}(x)=\left|f(x)-h(x)\right|^q$ where $q\geq 1$. Then
$$|l_{h,f}(x)|=\left|f(x)-h(x)\right|^q\leq \|f-h\|_{\mathcal{H}_{K}}^qK(x,x)^q.$$

If we denote by $\mathcal{H}_{K_1}$ as the smallest reproducing kernel Hilbert space containing $W=\{l_{h,f}:\,\,f,h\in\mathcal{H}_K\}$, and such that $$|g(x)|\leq \|g\|_{\mathcal{H}_{K}}^qK(x,x)^q.$$

This means that the [evaluation functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Definition) is bounded on $\mathcal{H}_1$. And follows that $$\|g\|_{\mathcal{H}_{K_1}}\leq \|g\|_{\mathcal{H}_{K}}^q.$$

**Note:**The suggested reference, in the referred paper, is related to this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/32164950_NORM_INEQUALITIES_IN_NONLINEAR_TRANSFORMSInequalities_in_operator_theory_and_its_related_topics. Perhaps it helps. Perhaps you find some helpful result serching, for instance, by "
\(\|f\|*{H_K}\leq \|f\|*{H_R}\)  RKHS" on SearchOnMath.