# Non-linear transforms of RKHS question

Tags: hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, kernels, learning-theory

I was reading the paper [Norm Inequalities in Nonlinear Transforms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/32164950_NORM_INEQUALITIES_IN_NONLINEAR_TRANSFORMSInequalities_in_operator_theory_and_its_related_topics) (referenced in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400855/why-is-this-nonlinear-transformation-of-an-rkhs-also-an-rkhs)) but ran into difficulties, so I was wondering if anyone could help?

I think I follow the paper until I get to the main result/theorem, which begins:

"If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |h_n(p)|^2 K(p,p)^{n} < \infty$ on $p \in E$ then ..."

My problem is that $h_n$ is never defined before, in, or immediately after the theorem.  My best guess is that this is a typo and should read $d_n(p)$ (which makes perfect sense in context, at least afaict, in light of discussion in the paragraph after equation (1.9)), but I have a niggling doubt given the recurrence of the $h_n$ notation much later in the paper.  Does my guess seem sensible, or have I missed something here?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly a typo. You can find the theorem in another [source](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-10-0530-5) by the same author, where $h_n$ is $d_n$:

[image]